# Why the value in ui text is flickering and how can I make it not to flicker?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the value in the text not to flickering when the player is moving but not sure ho to do it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerSpeedDistanceController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public GameObject speedArea;
    public float speed;
    public Animator animator;
    public Text movementSpeedUiText;
    public Text distanceFormTargetUiText;
    public Text playerDirectionUiText;

    private float distance;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private bool isMoving;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;
        isMoving = false;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        movementSpeedUiText.text = animator.GetFloat("Forward").ToString();
        distanceFormTargetUiText.text = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position).ToString();
        playerDirectionUiText.text = transform.forward.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isMoving == false)
        {
            movementSpeedUiText.text = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            movementSpeedUiText.text = animator.GetFloat("Forward").ToString();
        }
        distanceFormTargetUiText.text = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position).ToString();
        playerDirectionUiText.text = transform.forward.ToString();

        if (transform.position != lastPosition)
            isMoving = true;
        else
            isMoving = false;

        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

It's flickering on this line when the player is moving :

```
movementSpeedUiText.text = animator.GetFloat("Forward").ToString();
```

It didn't flicker before but since I added the movement check in the Update it's start flickering.
What is flickering is the value in the text.

I tried to change the Update to LateUpdate but it didn't fix the flickering only when changed it to FixedUpdate then it's working but is it a good idea to put it all in FixedUpdate ? And I see now that sometimes the value in the text is minus negative why and what should I do ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerSpeedDistanceController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public GameObject speedArea;
    public float speed;
    public Animator animator;
    public Text movementSpeedUiText;
    public Text distanceFormTargetUiText;
    public Text playerDirectionUiText;

    private float distance;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private bool isMoving;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;
        isMoving = false;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        movementSpeedUiText.text = animator.GetFloat("Forward").ToString();
        distanceFormTargetUiText.text = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position).ToString();
        playerDirectionUiText.text = transform.forward.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isMoving == false)
        {
            movementSpeedUiText.text = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            movementSpeedUiText.text = animator.GetFloat("Forward").ToString("F3");
        }
        distanceFormTargetUiText.text = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position).ToString();
        playerDirectionUiText.text = transform.forward.ToString();
        
        if (transform.position != lastPosition)
            isMoving = true;
        else
            isMoving = false;

        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to put it in the Lateupdate()

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII tried didn't work but it's working in FixedUpdate. But now I see that sometimes when the layer is moving the value is minus not all the time but in some times it's minus negative.  Any ideas why ?

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII Maybe I should use both Update and FixedUpdate ? Fixed for the UI text and Update for other stuff ?

Comment: what is the code for animator.getfloat("forward")? i guess its changing evrytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `Rigidbody` to move your object. The `Physics` system works together with the `FixedUpdate` which is executed in (as the name suggests) **fixed** time intervals - by default every `0.02` seconds.

So what happens if you put your code in `Update` might look somewhat like

```
u    u    u    u    u    u    u    u
f       f        f        f        f
```

where `u` stands for `Update` call and `f` stands for `FixedUpdate` call.

So since the `Physics` are applied a bit desync to `Update` if hard check the values of `transform.position` it might just happen that your object is not yet moved or stoped by the Physics system.

---

So yes, either put your stuff in `FixedUpdate` - nothing speaks against it.

Or instead of `transform.position` rather use [`rigidbody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html)

> Rigidbody.position allows you to get and set the position of a Rigidbody using the physics engine.

which is the correct position of the object in the physics engine, also between `FixedUpdate` calls.

Or actually there is a way better method for getting the current movement of a `Rigidbody` which doesn't require storing and comparing any previous frame values:

[`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

> The velocity vector of the rigidbody. It represents the rate of change of Rigidbody position.

So you can shrink down your code to

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerSpeedDistanceController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public GameObject speedArea;
    public float speed;
    public Text movementSpeedUiText;
    public Text distanceFormTargetUiText;
    public Text playerDirectionUiText;

    private float distance;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    private UpdateDisplay()
    {
        movementSpeedUiText.text = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude.ToString("0.###");
        distanceFormTargetUiText.text = Vector3.Distance(rigidbody.position, target.transform.position).ToString();
        playerDirectionUiText.text = transform.forward.ToString();
    }
}
```